# Как сделать, чтобы после упаковки ZIP библиотекой файлов, можно было открыть через проводник этот архив и увидеть файлы?

Tags: java, zip

Пишу архиватор на Java. Cобрал файлы в Zip архив, но, если открыть его через проводник виндовс, он как-будто пустой(не отображаются файлы). А нужно, чтобы пользователь открыл и увидел, что у него допустим 5 файлов в архиве и картинка.

Причем если распаковать кодом JAVA этот пустой с виду архив, то там действительно окажутся данные.
Какой параметр нужно установить при сжатии, что решить проблему?

```
//zip to test.zip
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File archive = new File("test.zip");
    if (!archive.exists()) {
        archive.createNewFile();
    }

    List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
    files.add(PATH_TO_FILE1);
    files.add(PATH_TO_FILE2);

    ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new CheckedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(archive), new CRC32()));
    BufferedOutputStream writer = new BufferedOutputStream(zip);

    for (String datFile : files) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(datFile));
        zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(datFile));

        int c;
        while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
            writer.write(c);
        }
        writer.flush();
        reader.close();
    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    //Unzip
    ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new CheckedInputStream(new FileInputStream(archive), new CRC32()));
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(zipInputStream);
    ZipEntry entry;
    while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Reading file " + entry);
        int c;
        while ((c = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) c);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    zipInputStream.close();
```

Comment: А в чём проблема-то?

Comment: Предположу, что проблема в использовании полного пути к файлам, из-за этого в `ZipEntry` попадает двоеточие, которое проводник не понимает. Еще вам нужно использовать `*InputStream` вместо `*Reader` для чтения файлов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо `putNextEntry()` нужно еще вызывать `closeEntry()`:

```
for (String datFile : files) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(datFile));
    zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(datFile));

    int c;
    while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
        writer.write(c);
    }
    writer.flush();
    reader.close();

    zip.closeEntry();
}
```

P.S. И обычно `ZipOutputStream` оборачивает `BufferedOutputStream`, а не наоборот.